# Errors while trying to make my first app with eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-developer-api

I am having 4 errors while trying to make my first app with eclipse.Please try to help me out  Here are the following:

1) Attribute is missing the android namespace

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F0A0A0A0"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" color="#A00080FF"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
```

2) Attribute is missing the android namespace

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
solid android:color="#F0FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" color="#A00080FF"/>
<padding android:left="5dp" android:top="0dp"
    android:right="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
```

3) Duplicate id @+id/image already defined earlier in this layout

4) Wrong orientation no orientation specified....

Answer (score 0):

for **1** and **2**

```
change color="#A00080FF"
```

to

```
android:color="#A00080FF"
```

for **3** check your layout xml file... it must have 2 imageviews with same android:id

and for **4** specify

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to your linear layout tag